# Assessing/Improving prediction with linear discriminant analysis or logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, analysis, lda

I recently needed to combine two or more variables on some data set to evaluate if their combination could enhance predictivity, thus I made some logistic regression in R. Now, on the statistic Q&A, someone suggested that I may use the linear discriminant analysis.

Since I don't have any `fitcdiscr.m` in MATLAB, I'd rather go with lda in R but I cannot use the fit results to predict AUC or whatever I could use. Indeed, I see that fit output vector of lda in R is some sort of vector with multiple classes and I guess I should use `fit$posterior` to predict Cases against Controls, but I cannot take those data out of it.

For further information, I get this results as `fit$posterior`:

```
$posterior
            0          1
1   0.7707927 0.22920726
2   0.7085165 0.29148352
3   0.6990989 0.30090106
4   0.5902161 0.40978387
5   0.8667109 0.13328912
6   0.6924406 0.30755939
7   0.7471086 0.25289141
8   0.7519326 0.24806736
```

And so on up to the last observation which is 242. Every time I try to take, for example, column 1 by `fit$posterior[,1]`, I get:

```
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
0.7707927 0.7085165 0.6990989 0.5902161 0.8667109 0.6924406 0.7471086 0.7519326 
        9        10        11        12        13        14        15        16 
0.7519326 0.6902850 0.7519326 0.8080445 0.8075360 0.8484318 0.4860899 0.8694121
```

I don't know which part of the code could be useful, since I made very basic computation:

```
library(gdata)
data=read.xls("ECGvarious.xls", perl="C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe");
i=6;
p=19;
temp=data[,i];
temp1=data[, p];
library(MASS)
fit <- lda(Case ~ temp + temp , data=data, na.action="na.omit", CV=TRUE)
```

I can't link the data, anyway ECGvarious is simply an N observation x P variables, being N= N1+ N2 with N1 the number of Controls and N2 the number of Cases, and the Cases are defined as subjects who developed pathology after a follow up. The very last column of data is just 0 or 1 for Controls and Cases, respectively.

When I performed the logistic regression, I did:

```
mod1<-glm(Case ~ temp + temp1, data=data,     family="binomial"); 
auctemp=auc(Case~predict(mod1), data=data);
```

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't include any data nor code...

Comment: I've included some code, i hope this helps. Moreover, i managed to extract the data in fit$posterior thorugh sapply function, but now i dont know how to compute AUC from the data since if i try to use the same formula used in the logistic regression such as auctemp=auc(Case~predict(fit$superior_column1), data=data);

Comment: ... i get this error : 
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: From what package is the `auc` function? I think you could get better answers by having a more focused question, and maybe asking it on Cross Validated. Just a note: if you use `predict(..., type="response")`, you'll get a probability, which might be easier to work with.

Comment: the package is pROC. Maybe 'll try on cross validated, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my input concerning *logistic regression and prediction* (I don't know much about linear discrimination but understand it's closely related to logistic regression, which I know much better). I'm not sure I'm following all of your reasoning, nor if this will be a satisfactory answer, but hopefully it won't hurt. This has been a review of some epidemiology classes for me. I hope it's not too formal and addresses at least in part some of your questions. If not, and if other users think this would better belong on Cross Validated, I won't take offense. :)

### Sample data

We'll first generate 200 observations, having increasing levels of probability for Case=1. The first predictor (`pred1`) will follow a distribution that is nonlinear, close to the one being modeled when doing logistic regression. It will be rather closely related to the proportion of Cases. The second predictor will just be random, uniformly distributed noise.

```
set.seed(2351)
df <- data.frame(Case = c(sample(c(0,1), size = 67, prob = c(0.8, 0.2), replace = TRUE), 
                          sample(c(0,1), size = 66, prob = c(0.5, 0.5), replace = TRUE), 
                          sample(c(0,1), size = 67, prob = c(0.2, 0.8), replace = TRUE)),
                 pred1 = 6/(1+4*exp(-seq(from = -3, to = 5, length.out = 200))) + rnorm(n = 200, mean = 2, sd=.5),
                 pred2 = runif(n = 200, min = 0, max = 100))
```

We see in the boxplot below that the observations where `case==1` generally have higher `pred1`, which is intended (from the way we generated the data). At the same time, there is an overlap, otherwise it would make it too easy to decide on a cutoff point/threshold.

```
boxplot(pred1 ~ Case, data=df, xlab="Case", ylab="pred1")
```

[image: boxplot]

### Fitting the logistic model

First using both predictors:

```
model.1 <- glm(Case ~ pred1 + pred2, data=df, family=binomial(logit))
summary(model.1)

# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept) -2.058258   0.479094  -4.296 1.74e-05 ***
# pred1        0.428491   0.075373   5.685 1.31e-08 ***
# pred2        0.003399   0.005500   0.618    0.537    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
#     Null deviance: 276.76  on 199  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 238.51  on 197  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 244.51
```

As we'd expect, the first predictor is rather strongly related, and the second, poorly related to the outcome.

Note that to get *Odds Ratios* from those coefficients, we need to exponentiate them:

```
exp(model.1$coefficients[2:3])

#    pred1    pred2 
# 1.534939 1.003405   # Odds Ratios (making the relationships appear more clearly). 
                      # Use `exp(confint(model.1))` to get confidence intervals.
```

We'll compare this model to a simpler model, removing the second predictor:

```
model.2 <- glm(Case ~ pred1, data=df, family=binomial(logit))
summary(model.2)

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept) -1.87794    0.37452  -5.014 5.32e-07 ***
# pred1        0.42651    0.07514   5.676 1.38e-08 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#
#     Null deviance: 276.76  on 199  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 238.89  on 198  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 242.89

exp(model.2$coefficients)[2]

#    pred1 
# 1.531907  # Odds Ratio
```

We could also run an `anova(model.1, model.2)`, but let's skip this part and move on to prediction, keeping this simpler model as the second variable doesn't add much predictive value, if any. In practive, having more predictors is rarely a problem unless it's truly random noise, but here I focus more on the operation of predicting and choosing a proper threshold.

### Stored predictions

In the `model.2` object (a list), there is an item named `fitted.values`. Those values are the exact same that we'd get from `predict(model.2, type="response")` and can be interpreted as probabilities; one for each row, based on the predictor(s) and their coefficient(s).

### New predictions

It is also possible to predict the outcome for hypothetical rows not in our initial dataframe.

With `model.1` (2 predictors):

```
predict(model.1, newdata = list(pred1=1, pred2=42), type="response")

#         1 
# 0.1843701
```

With `model.2` (1 predictor):

```
predict(model.2, newdata = list(pred1=12), type="response")

#       1 
# 0.96232
```

---

### Going from probability to binary response

Looking back at the link between our predictor `pred1` and the calculated probability of having `Case=1`:

```
plot(df$pred1, model.2$fitted.values, 
     xlab="pred1", ylab="probability that Case=1")
```

[image: P(case) against pred1]

*We note that since we have only one predictor, the probability is a direct function of it. If we had kept the other predictor in the equation, we'd see points grouped around the same line, but in a cloud of points.*

But this doesn't change the fact that if we are to evaluate how well our model can predict binary outcomes, we need to settle on a threshold above which we'll consider that the observation is a *Case*. Several packages have tools to help picking that threshold. But even without any additional package, we can calculate various properties over a range of thresholds using a function such as the following, which will calculate the *sensitivity* (ability to detect True *Cases*), *specificity* (ability to identify True *Non Cases*), and other properties well described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity).

```
df.ana <- data.frame(thresh=seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 0.5) / 100)
for(i in seq_along(df.ana$thresh)) {
    df.ana$sensitivity[i] <- sum(df$Case==1 & (predict(model.2, type="resp") >= df.ana$thresh[i])) / sum(df$Case==1)
    df.ana$specificity[i] <- sum(df$Case==0 & (predict(model.2, type="resp") < df.ana$thresh[i])) / sum(df$Case==0)
    df.ana$pos.pred.value[i] <- sum(df$Case == 1 & (predict(model.2, type="resp") >= df.ana$thresh[i])) / sum(predict(model.2, type="resp") >= df.ana$thresh[i])
    df.ana$neg.pred.value[i] <- sum(df$Case == 0 & (predict(model.2, type="resp") < df.ana$thresh[i])) / sum(predict(model.2, type="resp") < df.ana$thresh[i])
    df.ana$accuracy[i] <- sum((predict(model.2, type="resp") >= df.ana$thresh[i]) == df$Case) / nrow(df)
}

which.max(df.ana$accuracy)

# [1] 46 

optimal.thresh <- df.ana$thresh[which.max(df.ana$accuracy)] # 0.46
```

The accuracy is the proportion of correct predictions over all predictions. The 46th threshold (0.46) is the "best" for that matter. Let's check a few other neighboring rows in the generated dataframe; it tells us that 0.47 would work as well on all fronts. Fine-tuning would involve adding some new data to our initial dataframe.

```
df.ana[45:48,]

#    thresh sensitivity specificity pos.pred.value neg.pred.value accuracy
# 45   0.45   0.7142857   0.6947368      0.7211538      0.6875000    0.705
# 46   0.46   0.7142857   0.7157895      0.7352941      0.6938776    0.715
# 47   0.47   0.7142857   0.7157895      0.7352941      0.6938776    0.715
# 48   0.48   0.7047619   0.7157895      0.7326733      0.6868687    0.710
```

Note that the `auc` function (*area under the curve*) will give the same number as the accuracy for that threshold:

```
library(pROC)
auc(Case ~ as.numeric(predict(model.2, type="response") >= optimal.thresh), data=df)

# Area under the curve: 0.715
```

---

### Some plots

```
# thresholds against accuracy
plot(x=df.ana$thresh, y=df.ana$accuracy, type="l",
         xlab="Threshold", ylab="", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
text(x = 0.1, y = 0.5, labels = "Accuracy", col="black")

# thresholds against Sensitivity 
lines(x=df.ana$thresh, y=df.ana$sensitivity, type="l",col="blue") # Sensitivity We want to maximize this, but not too much
text(x = 0.1, y = 0.95, labels = "Sensitivity", col="blue")

# thresholds against specificity 
lines(x=df.ana$thresh, y=df.ana$specificity, type="l", col="red") # Specificity we want to maximize also, but not too much
text(x = 0.1, y = 0.05, labels = "Specificity", col="red")

# optimal threshold vertical line
abline(v=optimal.thresh)
text(x=optimal.thresh + .01, y=0.05, labels= optimal.thresh)
```

[image: Accuracy sensitivity specificity]

Incidentally, all lines converge more or less to the same point, which suggests this is a good compromise between all the qualities we look for in a predictive tool. But depending on your objectives, it might be better picking a lower or a higher threshold. Statistical tools are useful, but in the end, some other considerations are often more important in making a final decision.

### About ROC

The following graph is the same as the one which would be produced with pROC's roc:

```
plot(x=df.ana$specificity, y = df.ana$sensitivity, type="l", col="blue",
         xlim = c(1,0), xlab = "Specificity", ylab = "Sensitivity") 

# Equivalent to
# plot(roc(predictor=model.2$fitted.values, response = model.2$y))
```

[image: ROC]

---

### Tabulations and other stats

The following function allows one to calculate, for a logistic model fit, the same stats seen above, and gives a 2x2 table for any chosen threshold.

```
diagnos.test <- function(model, threshold) {
    output <- list()
    output$stats <- c(
      sensitivity = sum(model.1$y==1 & (predict(model, type="resp") >= threshold)) / sum(model.1$y==1),
      specificity = sum(model.1$y==0 & (predict(model, type="resp") < threshold)) / sum(model.1$y==0),
      pos.pr.value = sum(model.1$y==1 & (predict(model.2, type="resp") >= threshold)) / sum(predict(model.2, type="resp") >= threshold),
      neg.pr.value = sum(df$Case == 0 & (predict(model.2, type="resp") < threshold)) / sum(predict(model.2, type="resp") < threshold),
      accuracy = sum((predict(model.2, type="resp") >= threshold) == df$Case) / nrow(df))
    output$tab <- addmargins(t(table(model$y, as.numeric(predict(model, type="response") > threshold),dnn = list("Cases", "Predictions")))[2:1,2:1])
    return(output)
}

diagnos.test(model.2, 0.47)

# $stats
#  sensitivity  specificity pos.pr.value neg.pr.value     accuracy 
#    0.7142857    0.7157895    0.7352941    0.6938776    0.7150000 
# 
# $tab
#            Cases
# Predictions   1  0 Sum
#         1    75 27 102
#         0    30 68  98
#         Sum 105 95 200
```

---

**Final note**

I don't pretend I have covered everything on prediction, sensitivity and specificity; my goal was more to go as far as possible using common language and calculations, not relying on any specific packages.

Comment: Looks like you put great effort to answer this (+1)

Comment: Thanks @akrun, yes I did, and it was a good review of some of my class material, too! :)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this answer. One question: when you computed the optimal threshold, you cycle from 0 to 100 and i cant understand if these are the standard range for 0 to 100% or if they are dependant on the range of the pred1, since i've tried to see the difference between what i found simply doing auc(Case~VarN, data=data) and doing the logistic on VarN and then applying your code. Indeed, i found that the two cases bring to different auc results for the same Var1, but i also found that i get the same results using different Var, which are however characterized by the same units

Comment: The thresholds ranging from 0 to 100 were chosen arbitrarily. Actually some don't really make sense since the range of the predicted probabilities don't reach those limits (the actual range is `[0.209 ;  0.885]`. For the rest I'm not sure I'm following, and I'm getting pretty tired... maybe I'll try coming back to it tomorrow. But the thresholds should not be related to the predictors in any direct way, given that the scales are not the same, if you know what I mean...

Comment: I'm not sure to have understood. I'll try to explain better. Suppose i have the 2 variables: Left Ventricular ejection fraction, which is the quantity of blood ejected in every heartbeat, and the RR interval, which is the duration of an heartbeat. The former is expressed as percentage, thus ranging from 0 to 100, while the latter is expressed in millseconds, with a varying duration with min or max depending on each subject. How do you set the thresholds range?

Comment: The threshold needs to be set on the model's prediction value - which is, when you use `type="response"`, the probability of having a case (Case=1). This probability relies on calculations implying each of your predictors and their coefficients (Betas). So you don't want to set a threshold on a predictor alone - unless it's your only one and it a pretty damn good predictor of your outcome!

Comment: Okay let's see if i get it right. Instead of evaluating threshold from the variable,  you define thresholds based on the value of the model's prediction. Thus brings another question: min and max threshold then wont be best if set as min and max of that value? Some kind of this

df.ana <- data.frame(thresh=seq(from = min(model.2), to = max(model.2) , by = ?) / max(model.2)?)

Comment: It won't _hurt_ to have useless threshold in the df.ana dataframe; after all, it is based on what this dataframe _contains_ that you will pick the right cutoff value for predicting events with your model... So you could have them all from 0 to 1 by increments of your choice... This will in fact allow you to produce graphs like the ones I show in my answer, graphs that will span all values from 0 to 1...