# Plot ROC curve: Error in seq.default(min.alpha, max.alpha, length = length(colors)) : 'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a ROC curve based on outcome (ED) and predicted class (p) using RORR package. I got the following error and I don't have any idea about that.

Error in seq.default(min.alpha, max.alpha, length = length(colors)) : 'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite.

```
library(arules)
library(Matrix)
library(ROCR)
library(arulesViz)
pred <- prediction(p, ED)
perf <- performance(pred, measure="tpr", x.measure="fpr")
plot(perf, main="ROC Curve", colorize=T)
```

I need to plot ROC for ZeroR, OneR, Decision tree, logistic regression and Linear discriminant analysis. In some of the methods, the predicted value would be probabilities (such as logistic regression) and in some of them (ZeroR), the predicted values would be 0/1.

I appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Thanks,
Mahsa

Comment: Can you provide sample data? Either `dput` on your `p` & `ED` or, if too lengthy, the `head` of those with reasonable number of rows. This way you'll get much better chances of getting help!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the data but in this case the P is always 0 and the ED can be either 0/1. I used ZeroR model and I want to plot a ROC curve.

Comment: This is interesting and I'd like to help more but I can't right now... What I can suggest is that you look at one answer I gave recently to another SO user, on logistic regression and prediction, and a small part is dedicated to ROC curves: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292678/assessing-improving-prediction-with-linear-discriminant-analysis-or-logistic-reg/29384319#29384319

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your model always predicts the same class and so the ROC curve is coincident with the 45 degree line, resulting in a single non-infinite value for `alpha.values` in the `perf` object. This causes `plot` to throw an error when `colorize` is set to `TRUE`. I'll explain this in more detail below using the built-in data frame `ROCR.simple`, with which I was able to reproduce your problem.

```
# Load ROCR.simple data frame
data(ROCR.simple)
```

First, we'll change the predictions to always predict label=0, by setting `ROCR.simple$predictions` to be less than 0.5). That's just in order to make it look like your results.

```
ROCR.simple$predictions = rep(0.1, length(ROCR.simple$predictions))
```

Now we'll run code similar to yours:

```
pred = prediction(ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)

perf = performance(pred, measure="tpr", x.measure="fpr")
```

Now let's look at `perf`:

```
perf

An object of class "performance"
Slot "x.name":
  [1] "False positive rate"

Slot "y.name":
  [1] "True positive rate"

Slot "alpha.name":
  [1] "Cutoff"

Slot "x.values":
  [[1]]
[1] 0 1

Slot "y.values":
  [[1]]
[1] 0 1

Slot "alpha.values":
  [[1]]
[1] Inf 0.1
```

Finally, let's try to plot it:

```
# This fails
plot(perf, colorize=TRUE)

Error in seq.default(min.alpha, max.alpha, length = length(colors)) : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite

# This works
plot(perf)
```

Based on these results, I think what's going on is that when you set `colorize=TRUE`, `plot` tries to create a sequence of colors from the lowest to the highest value of `alpha.values` (see `perf@alpha.values` above), but this (or perhaps a later function that creates the legend for the colors) fails with the error message you're getting when there is only one non-infinite value in `alpha.values`.

And, as I noted at the beginning, this error is happening ultimately because your model always predicts the same class (that is, it has no predictive power).