# Cutoff value for Logistic regression for max Specificity and sensitivity

Tags: r, logistic-regression, roc

I am trying to see the cutoff value where sensitivity and Specificity are maximum. 
However, my logistic regression gives a response in probability. I am trying the code below.

```
pred_Cutoff <- predict(GLM, newdata = testData,type = "response")
roc <- performance(pred_Cutoff,"tpr","fpr")
plot(roc,colorize=T)
```

Obviously, my I cannot compare performance between probability and a binary value. If I specify a threshold for changing probability to binary, that doesn't make any sense. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can use ks statistic to determine the cutoff

Comment: Can you please help me with the code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292678/assessing-improving-prediction-with-linear-discriminant-analysis-or-logistic-reg/29384319#29384319

Comment: Are you asking how to use ROC analysis to choose the cutoff? Or how to get a binary output out of `predict` (but then ROC analysis isn't useful)? Why are you saying that specifying a threshold doesn't make any sense?

Comment: I cannot develop the Roc unless I specify a threshold (for example 0.5) to transform the probability to binary. If I have already specified the threshold, whats the use of cutoff value?